# How to get QtWebEngineView in ptqt5 using python 3.4 on windows?

Tags: pyqt, qtwebengine

I tried pyqt 5.5 but it's showing unused import...unable to find keyword qtwebengineview or qt webenginewidgets  Thanks..appreciate your time

Comment: can you show your effort here?

Comment: Show the full error message, and explain what you did to produce it.

Comment: Yeah i can show..here is the code where i'm importing webenginewidget:
 
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebKit,QtWebEngineWidget

But it shows error usused import:
and if i run it give this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Eclipse\flivis\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebKit,QtWebEngineWidget
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidget'

Comment: thanks for your reply

Comment: @Akshay14. You're missing an "s": QtWebEngineWidget**s**.

Comment: @ekhumoro yeah that was my mistake in copy paste.. but even though it's not woking:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\Eclipse\flivis\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebKit,QtWebEngineWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets'

there is no packet named qtwebengine or qtwebenginewidget in pyqt 5 folder

Comment: @Akshay14. It looks like QtWebEngineWidgets is [not available on Windows](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/introduction.html#module-PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets).

Comment: Yeah that's the problem....thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue now by updating to pyqt5.9,

```
pip install PyQt5 --update
```

should do the trick. Once it's installed you'll need to import it with:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```